# Compass - Get width and height of generated sprite-map

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sass, compass-sass

I'm building a Sencha Touch mobile application and are using the functionality to create image-sprite-maps with Compass.

Is there any way to calculate the size of the image-map (width and height) and put it as a variable in your SCSS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Compass, [image-height](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/image-dimensions/#image-height) and [image-width](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/image-dimensions/#image-width) are the functions to get image dimensions. Using them with your sprite map would look something like this (warning, untested):

```
// Assuming $my-sprites is your sprite map variable
$map-path: sprite-path($my-sprites);

$map-height: image-height($map-path);
$map-width: image-width($map-path);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in the latest version of Sass (3.4). sprite-path returns the full filesystem path while image-width expects a path relative to the images directory. No sure why they changed it.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Sass (3.4) sprite-path() returns the full filesystem path while image-width() expects a path relative to the images directory. But there is a simple solution:

```
sprite-width($sprite-map);
sprite-height($sprite-map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a unit value by using the magical dimension functions `<map>-sprite-height` and `<map>-sprite-width`.

```
// Note: "my-icons" represents the folder name that contains your sprites.

@import "my-icons/*.png";
$box-padding: 5px;
$height: my-icons-sprite-height(some_icon);
$width: my-icons-sprite-width(some_icon);

.somediv {
  height:$height + $box-padding;
  width:$width + $box-padding;
}
```

Check the [official documentation](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Ext.getBody().getSize() gets you height and width of the screen but i dont think you can write this in SASS